# Validation Summary via Screen Readers

Tags: asp.net, accessibility, wcag, validationsummary

I have an asp:ValidationSummary control. I have the markup as below:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="validationsummary" ValidationGroup="ApplicantLoginGroup" ClientIDMode="Static" aria-live="assertive" />
```

When there is a validation error, the screen reader does say "alert", but does not read out the errors listed in the summary section.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share the html code that is generated containing the error? It can then be reverse engineered to see how the output needs to be modified for assistive technologies to read it correctly.

Comment: Here is the HTML code generated:

  <div id="LoginValidationSummary" class="validationsummary" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" role="list" style="color:Red;">
  <ul><li>First name is required.</li><li>Last name is required.</li></ul>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of requirements a website should meet to pass validation. So, I never tried to implement accessibility support by myself. I used [DX editors](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/Accessibility/Compliance.aspx) (and several other controls) to support accessibility in my applications. They support WCAG and Section 508.